# Difference between Dicke superradiance and dipole-coupled emitter superradiance

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-optics, interactions, collective-excitations

This question is similar to "[What causes the collective emission in Dicke Model?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/597904/what-causes-the-collective-emission-in-dicke-model)", but more specific. I wonder if the situation described in

[1] [R. H. Dicke – *Coherence in Spontaneous Radiation Processes.* Physical Review 93(1), 99–110 (1954)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.93.99)

generally describes dipole-coupled emitters, as for example experimentally shown in

[2] [C. Hettich *et al.* – *Nanometer Resolution and Coherent Optical Dipole Coupling of Two Individual Molecules.* Science 298, 385–389 (2002)](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.1075606).

The theoretical model for 2 emitters is derived for example in

[3] [U. Akram *et al.* – *Decoherence and coherent population transfer between two coupled systems.* Physical Review A 62(1), 013413 (2000)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.62.013413).

---

Dicke [1] describes gas in a transparent sub-wavelength vessel, where

> all the molecules are interacting with a common radiation field and hence cannot be treated as independent.

Moreover, the molecules are considered as two-level-systems with identical transition frequencies. The Hamiltonian of the system consists of the excited-state energy of all molecules (Eq. 4) plus a field interaction term for each molecule (Eq. 15). He then shows that some initial states have increased/decreased emission rates.

---

Akram *et al.* [3] describe a situation with exactly 2 emitters, but include an additional set of parameters, like different resonance frequencies $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$, arbitrary relative position and orientation and even different decay rates $\Gamma_1$, $\Gamma_2$. The Hamiltonian is the sum of the excited-state energies, the energy of all electromagnetic modes, an interaction between each emitter and the electromagnetic field (and a laser drive term) (Eq. 2). Using the Lindblad master equation (which wasn't developed in Dicke's time), they derive a general expression for the interaction energy $\delta_{12} \sim {r_{12}}^{-3}$ due to the coupling to common electromagnetic modes (Eq. 25) as function of the relative position $r_{12}$ of the emitters. This leads to a hybridization of the energy eigenstates into super- and subradiant states, with decay rate faster/slower by the cross-damping rate $\Gamma_{12} \sim \sqrt{\Gamma_1 \Gamma_2}$.

---

My question is:

Is the origin of super-/subradiance in both theories the same or am I missing subtle differences? In [3] they cite [1], but not in a context which makes clear that they describe the same phenomenon. What confused me in Dicke's paper [1] is in particular a remark on the first page that "dipole-dipole interaction is negligible".